# Cancel Output Caching in ChildAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if it's possible to cancel output caching in code? What I mean is if I place output caching on a child action as follows can I then based on a condition cancel that caching from inside the child action?

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration = 36000, VaryByParam="tagslug")]
public virtual ActionResult MostViewed(string tagslug, int count)
{
    // Make an API call here. If not data returned do not cache the ChildAction as specified above
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming [the framework source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) it looks like the only logic is don't-cache-on-exception:

```
// Only cache output if this wasn't an error
if (!wasException) {
    ChildActionCacheInternal.Add(uniqueId, capturedText,
                                 DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Duration));
}
```

I can't see a brilliant way to solve this: I think you'll have to make your own custom `OutputCachingAttribute` based on the original source from the ASP.NET MVC source from CodePlex, and then either add an extra check to that line for the output returned e.g.

```
if (!(wasException || capturedText.Contains("results:0"))) {
```

or similar, or find a way to pass that code a flag to this from your controller. The existing code uses an object to store a value on the session; you could copy this, e.g.

1. define a new static object key the same as `_childActionFilterFinishCallbackKey` e.g. `_noCacheResultKey`
2. add a public static method to the attribute that you can call e.g.

   ```
   public static void FlagNoCache(HttpContext httpContext) {
       httpContext.Items[_noCacheResultKey] = true;
   }
   ```
3. extend `ClearChildActionFilterFinishCallback` to remove this from `.Items[]` as well as the callback
4. extend the above test to check this too e.g.

   ```
   if (!(wasException
         || filterContext.HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey(_noCacheResultKey))) {
   ```
5. from your controller call `MyOutputCacheAttribute.FlagNoCache(Context);` as necessary.

It may also be possible to throw an exception from your code and then catch it in a different `IExceptionFilter` so that it doesn't get passed up beyond the `OutputCacheAttribute` but I don't know how sorry.